# How can I use the <input> method, the <onclick = "func()">, and javascript to change the background color of my page

Tags: html

This is my current code for this issue. Is there anything that I can put inside the script tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Color picker
</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <h1> COLOR PICKER </h1>
    <label for="R">R: </label>
    <input type="number" maxlength="3" min="0" max="255" id="r">
    <label for="G">G: </label>
    <input type="number" maxlength="3" min="0" max="255" id="g">
    <label for="B">B: </label>
    <input type="number" maxlength="3" min="0" max="255" id="b"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="getColor()">Get color</input>
    <script>
    function getColor() {
        var r = document.getElementById("r");
        var g = document.getElementById("g");
        var b = document.getElementById("b"); 
        var color = "rgb("+ [r,g,b].join(',')")";
        document.body.style.background = color;
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

For instance with input: R: 255, G: 0, B: 255 and when I want the page should be a magenta color. But when I actually press the button nothing happens. Can I do something to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `.value` of each `input` element.

```
    var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
    var g = document.getElementById("g").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
```

and  you are also missing a `+` on your string concatenation

```
var color = "rgb(" + [r,g,b].join(',') + ")";
```

Comment: also you are missing `<form> </form>` tag which will make sure the `min` ,`max` works

Comment: It still works without the form tag @Mohamed Fathallah

Comment: The code works.